# How to pass array of strings to a main()

Tags: c++, string

I have not been successful on searching for this topic.  I want to pass an array of strings to a C++ console app.  The closest I have found is using argv(), but the number (variable) may be 50 strings which would be ugly on the calling side.

Is it possible to pass an array, or a structure to main()?  I am totally open to which way to go, I have almost no experience with interprocess communication.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at fgetc(stdin)

Answer (score 3):

The conventional approach is just STDIN, as then you can send in *whatever* using pipes or redirection. As in: `program < input`

The second option is your first argument is a file to read this data from. As in `program input.file`

There are conventions that accommodate both, like where `-` as a filename is presumed to mean "read STDIN", or where no filename given means read from STDIN (e.g. `grep`), so you can have it both ways.

If your strings contain newlines which complicate framing you may want to use a format like INI, JSON, or YAML to read in the data.

Comment: I should have mentioned the fact that the console app will be called by another application.  So STDIN is out. I have thought of using a file as intermediary, but the other program writing and the console app reading would be slow.  I am seeking some sort of transfer through memory (if possible).

Comment: @FWE1 So a memory mapped file would work then?  Or a shared memory segment?  What OS are you using?

Comment: Why is STDIN "out"? Why would it be "slow"? It's very quick to read either from a file or through a pipe. Another program can easily spawn this one and pipe data to it, this is a very common pattern used by a *lot* of tools spanning back decades. Using a pipe for IPC is extremely common and very efficient, more so than using files since no disk activity actually occurs.

Comment: OS is Windows. My code is C++, the calling program is most likely Java.  I have no experience with IPC, but I have seen named pipes mentioned. I would like to find a good tutorial on that.  My compiler is an old Borland one, loading a million string file is very quick using TStringList->LoadFromFile().  Clearing that memory, not fast at all. Loading using Fstream>>basic-string in a loop is not nearly as quick.  I thought STDIN was console input (keyboard).

Comment: Why are you using some ancient compiler? There's a variety of free ones that are current and far better. I'm not sure what "clearing that memory" means as usually releasing memory is veyr low cost. STDIN is not necessarily keyboard input, though it can be, it's just a filehandle that can be used for *whatever*.